# What is the right way to render list on edit/create page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I've started to learn Angular js and have a question.
I want to render incomes list on edit and create pages. What is the right way to do it?

I use rails as backend. Now I have 3 different templates that render on different urls.

Example:

When you go to /incomes he see incomes list.

When you go to /incomes/new he see incomes list and create form.

When you go to /incomes/:id/edit he see incomes list and edit form.

Here is an image what i want to do.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

define a resource in your routes file that will generate the url's you want.

```
resources :incomes
```

This will generates the url like in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

Comment: how it will help me to render on edit page incomes? I was talking about angular js not rails.